# How to check a TCM URI is valid without raising an exception?

Tags: 2013, tom.net, api

Is there is some way in the TOM.NET API to check if an item exists (using TCM URI or WebDAV URL) without raising an exception?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Session.IsExistingObject` Method will not throw exception